# Exported .NET Core 2.1 App project template does not generate files

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After exporting a new project template in VS2017. When using the template to create a new project the project is empty.  The project is built with .NET Core 2.1. I had read other stackoverflow posts and saw that adding true  When I add this though the template cannot be found when going to create a new project in VS.

Here is the vstemplate file.

```js
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>CCCCore2Angular6Template</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
 <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
    <DefaultName>CCCCore2Angular6Template</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="CCCCore2Angular6Template.csproj" File="CCCCore2Angular6Template.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="launchSettings.json">launchSettings.json</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="wwwroot" TargetFolderName="wwwroot" />
      <Folder Name="ContractorConnection" TargetFolderName="ContractorConnection">
        <Folder Name=".git" TargetFolderName=".git" />
        <Folder Name="e2e" TargetFolderName="e2e">
          <Folder Name="src" TargetFolderName="src">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.e2e-spec.ts">app.e2e-spec.ts</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.po.ts">app.po.ts</ProjectItem>
          </Folder>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="protractor.conf.js">protractor.conf.js</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tsconfig.e2e.json">tsconfig.e2e.json</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="src" TargetFolderName="src">
          <Folder Name="app" TargetFolderName="app">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.component.css">app.component.css</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.component.html">app.component.html</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.component.spec.ts">app.component.spec.ts</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.component.ts">app.component.ts</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="app.module.ts">app.module.ts</ProjectItem>
          </Folder>
          <Folder Name="assets" TargetFolderName="assets">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName=".gitkeep">.gitkeep</ProjectItem>
          </Folder>
          <Folder Name="environments" TargetFolderName="environments">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="environment.prod.ts">environment.prod.ts</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="environment.ts">environment.ts</ProjectItem>
          </Folder>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="browserslist">browserslist</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="favicon.ico">favicon.ico</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="index.html">index.html</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="karma.conf.js">karma.conf.js</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="main.ts">main.ts</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="polyfills.ts">polyfills.ts</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="styles.css">styles.css</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="test.ts">test.ts</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tsconfig.app.json">tsconfig.app.json</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tsconfig.spec.json">tsconfig.spec.json</ProjectItem>
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tslint.json">tslint.json</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName=".editorconfig">.editorconfig</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName=".gitignore">.gitignore</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="angular.json">angular.json</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="package.json">package.json</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="package-lock.json">package-lock.json</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="README.md">README.md</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tsconfig.json">tsconfig.json</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="tslint.json">tslint.json</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="Controllers" TargetFolderName="Controllers">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="BaseController.cs">BaseController.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ValuesController.cs">ValuesController.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="Models" TargetFolderName="Models">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="UserModel.cs">UserModel.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="Services" TargetFolderName="Services">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="SessionExtensions.cs">SessionExtensions.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="SessionFields.cs">SessionFields.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="__PreviewImage.png">__PreviewImage.png</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="__TemplateIcon.png">__TemplateIcon.png</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="appsettings.json">appsettings.json</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="appsettings.Development.json">appsettings.Development.json</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Program.cs">Program.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="README.txt">README.txt</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Startup.cs">Startup.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: Which `MyTemplate.vstemplate` did you change? After exporting template from VS 2017, it will be saved to `C:\Users\[user name]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates` and will be imported to `C:\Users\edwardzh\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates`, you need to change `MyTemplate.vstemplate` in later one.

Comment: This has been checked.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue, could you share us a project to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Edward What is the best way to share this project template with you?

Comment: Github or onedrive

Comment: @Edward https://github.com/ajborn/Angular6CoreTemplate

Comment: For the project you shared, it missed `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` in `MyTemplate.vstemplate`. Please try unzip this template, modify `MyTemplate.vstemplate` to insert `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>`. zip this folder again.

Comment: @Edward Added the new zip to the project with the CreateInPlace tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure which template you are used and the result you got.

For your firest upload, it did not add `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` in `MyTemplate.vstemplate` which is required.

For your second post, it added **additional folder** in `zip` file which even will not create the template project in VS.

Please follow steps below:

1. delete the `CCCCore2Angular6Template.zip` under the `Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
2. open VS to make sure there is no `CCCCore2Angular6Template` under project template
3. Download and copy [CCCCore2Angular6Template.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hg0_LTHIyRbL38RF) to `Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
4. Check the result in VS

Comment: I think youre misunderstanding the steps I have already taken.  I had put two zip files in the repo, for reference. Your steps do not work. I placed the zip with with the <CreateInPlace> tag inside the ProjectTemplates directory and does not appear in the template list when creating a new project.

Comment: Have you made a test with my zip? Your second uploaded zip would not work.

Comment: The second zip doesnt work because of the <CreateInPlace> tag is inside the vstemplate.  You did not provide a zip file for me to try,

Comment: No, your second zip add one extact Folder, you could unzip it to check.

Comment: I understand what you mean now

Comment: So, what is the current result?

Comment: The template is now working after adding the CreateInPlace tag to the VSTemplate and zipping the files properly. They should not be zipped in a folder.